# Does UIImage(contentsOfFile: <String>) take into consideration screen scale?

Tags: ios, uiimage

I have an image on disk and load it like so:

```
guard let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: url.path!) else { return }
self.testImageView.image = image
```

When loading an image like this form file, will the image be drawn on screen with the correct scale factor?

I am asking because when I do this:

```
guard let imageData = NSData(contentsOfFile: url.path!) else { return }            
guard let image = UIImage(data: imageData, scale: UIScreen.mainScreen().scale) else { return }
self.testImageView.image = image
```

the image looks way sharper.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [Apple Documentation on supporting High-Resolution Screens In Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/SupportingHiResScreensInViews/SupportingHiResScreensInViews.html) which can be found in the [Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH1-SW1):

> On devices with high-resolution screens, the imageNamed:, imageWithContentsOfFile:, and initWithContentsOfFile: methods automatically looks for a version of the requested image with the @2x modifier in its name. If it finds one, it loads that image instead. If you do not provide a high-resolution version of a given image, the image object still loads a standard-resolution image (if one exists) and scales it during drawing.

Comment: It would be nice if you could clarify the reason for the downvote :)